# PHP: How to json encode of hindi language in response

Tags: php, json, hindi

I am working with a translation API but here is an issue. I am using JSON in response and when I do json_encode of Hindi then the out is like "\u092f\u0939 \u0915\u093e\u0930 \u0939\u0948"

My code is given below

```
$data = array();
$data['hindi'] = 'यह कार है';
$data['english'] = 'This is car';
echo json_encode($data); die;
```

and the response is

```
{"hindi":"\u092f\u0939 \u0915\u093e\u0930 \u0939\u0948","english":"This is car"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct json and when you display it in the browser and / or parse it, it will result in an object with the correct keys and values:

```js
var json_string = '{"hindi":"\u092f\u0939 \u0915\u093e\u0930 \u0939\u0948","english":"This is car"}',
    json = JSON.parse(json_string);

// or directly:
var json2 = {"hindi":"\u092f\u0939 \u0915\u093e\u0930 \u0939\u0948","english":"This is car"};

console.log(json_string);
console.log(json);
console.log(json2);

document.write(json_string);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(json.hindi);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(json2.hindi);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are running PHP 5.4 or greater, pass the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`parameter when calling `json_encode`

Example:

```
$data = array();
$data['hindi'] = 'यह कार है';
$data['english'] = 'This is car';
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
die;
```

Comment: Depending on where you want to use the JSON, however, not escaping the characters might cause problems. If he only uses it locally, simply `json_decode`ing the JSON again should give him back the original text.

Comment: OK but Now the response is not in JSON but it is showing string only

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is likely that these characters are not in UTF-8 (I could not find them, at least). [From the PHP documentation on json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

This means that it will have to convert it to a 'description' of the characters. Do not worry, if you decode it again it will very likely be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem. It works fine for me.

```
$data = array();
$data['hindi'] = base64_encode('यह कार है');
$data['english'] = 'This is car';
$encoded_text=json_encode($data);
```

To retrieve the hindi part of data:

```
$hindi=base64_decode(json_decode($encoded_text)->hindi);
```